# Double nested loop in Django HTML template not getting desired results

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have been staring at this one for a while and need some help.

I am trying to display a 'quit' button instead of a 'book' button on days where a logged in user has already booked into a session. Can someone please provide some guidance here?

## Models

```
class Member(models.Model):
    gym = models.ForeignKey(Gym, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="gym_membership")
    member = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="member_of_gym")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.member.username}'

class Session(models.Model):
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="session_program")
    focus = models.ForeignKey(Focus, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="session_focus")
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="session_location")
    booking_counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    start_datetime: datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = models.DurationField()
    day = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    week_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.program}, {self.day} - Week {self.week_number}'


class Booking(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="member_booking")
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="booking_session")
    booking = models.BooleanField()
    date_booked = models.DateTimeField()
    date_cancelled = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    attendance_verified = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.member.member.username} booked {self.session}'
```

## Views

```
def index(request):
    # store the user information in a variable
    user = request.user
    # get the membership object for that user
    member = Member.objects.get(member=user.id)
    context = {
        "sessions": Session.objects.all(),
        "bookings": Booking.objects.filter(member=member)
    }
    return render(request, "booking/index.html", context)
```

## index.html

```
{% extends "booking/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <h2>INTERFACE</h2>

    <p>WEEK X < ></p>
    <br>

    <class class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          BOOKINGS
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            {% for session in sessions %}
                <li class="list-group-item">{{ session.day }}: <a href="{% url 'session' session.id %}">{{ session.program }} </a>
                    <form class="nav-item ms-auto float-end" action="{% url 'book' session.id %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
{#                        {% for booking in bookings %}#}
                        {% for booking in session.booking_session %}
                            {% if booking.session == session %}
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light ms-auto btn-sm">quit</button>
                            {% else %}
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light ms-auto btn-sm">book</button>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </form>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </class>

{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, I have experimented with a nested for loop in the index.html sample. I have had two attempts get me close to what I want (see the commented out line in index.html) but to no avail.

My initial approach of generating all Sessions as one variable (to show all sessions) and then generating a list of the Bookings made by the user currently logged in (the list to show which rows of sessions need a quit button - instead of a book button) made perfect sense to me.

However, executing this has been troublesome. Please help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Can you give more context

Comment: Some design considerations are keeping a lot of logic outside of the templates and restricting them to views and models. You should filter the sessions such that there is a list of sessions booked by the currently logged in user and another list of sessions which are not booked  by the currently logged in user. You can still have these list displayed in a single template and decide what to do with it. 
A even better move is to have booked sessions displayed on their dashboard and a list of sessions which are not yet booked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's advisable to centralize the majority of application logic within views, steering away from intricate operations in templates to mitigate potential performance bottlenecks.

Now, let's address the specific code concerns. A logical flaw is evident in your current implementation. The inner loop checks if `booking.session == session`, which will invariably evaluate to `True` since you are iterating over `session.booking_session` (`{% for booking in session.booking_session %}`).

Regarding the alternative option you commented out, `{% for booking in bookings %}`, this should work as expected. I recommend revisiting this approach and cross-checking your database to ensure there are indeed bookings related to sessions.

For a more robust solution, consider utilising the `annotate` function in `Django`, as demonstrated in the refactored code snippet below:

```py
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, IntegerField


def index(request):
    # Store the user information in a variable
    user = request.user

    # Get the membership object for that user
    member = Member.objects.get(member=user.id)

    # Use annotate to add a 'has_member_booking' attribute to each session
    sessions = Session.objects.annotate(
        has_member_booking=Count(
            Case(
                When(booking_session__member=member, then=1),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )
    )

    context = {
        "sessions": sessions,
    }

    return render(request, "booking/index.html", context)
```

Then in your template

```html
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    {% for session in sessions %}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            {{ session.day }}: <a href="{% url 'session' session.id %}">{{ session.program }} </a>
            <form class="nav-item ms-auto float-end" action="{% url 'book' session.id %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if session.has_member_booking %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light ms-auto btn-sm">quit</button>
                {% else %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light ms-auto btn-sm">book</button>
                {% endif %}
            </form>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This not only addresses the performance concerns but also provides a more elegant and efficient solution for handling the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Temi I have the solution.

I had to make some small additional edits to the index.html to execute the quit view when pressing the quit button, and likewise for the book button.

These changes I made were a lack of detail on my part in writing the original description.

```
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        {% for session in sessions %}
            <li class="list-group-item">
                {{ session.day }}: <a href="{% url 'session' session.id %}">{{ session.program }} </a>
                    {% if session.has_member_booking %}
                        <form class="nav-item ms-auto float-end" action="{% url 'quit' session.id %}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light ms-auto btn-sm">quit</button>
                        </form>
                    {% else %}
                        <form class="nav-item ms-auto float-end" action="{% url 'book' session.id %}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-light ms-auto btn-sm">book</button>
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

I am now aware of the annotate() function to be used in views, so this is now a new tool for my Django toolbox.

Thanks @Temi.